# next build && next export do 2 folders build

Tags: next.js

`next build && next export`  when I use this command to build my project for production , I see 2 folders created `.next` and `out`, as I see `out` folders is enought for my project, is it ok ? or how can I prevent creating `.next` folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `out` folder content is enough, it contains all the static files that you would need, you can send them to CDN or serve as is.

You can just delete `.next` folder after `next export` if you want to. Like that for example: `next build && next export && rm -rf ./next`

Comment: Does it mean that out depend on .next, because we need to run the next build ?

Comment: Not sure what mean by "depend".